# Dúvidas de UML para sistema em Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, modelagem, uml

Minha dúvida é a seguinte. Os controllers do Rails, para as operações básicas do CRUD, necessitam de vários métodos que se repetem ao longo dos controllers da aplicação. Estou desenhando os diagramas para uma aplicação de TCC que possui vários CRUD's, e sendo assim, estou achando os diagramas de classes muito repetitivos.

Por exemplo, Tenho as classes Employees, Clients e Products. Todas elas possuem os métodos new, create, index, show, edit, update, delete e destroy. Ficar repetindo isso nos diagramas das três classes pode levantar a questão: "Mas uma herança não seria melhor?". Talvez, e inclusive não iria ferir o DRY. Agora, eis a questão. Como posso fazer isso? Alguém tem algo a sugerir? Ou essa repetição nos diagramas não tem problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu diagrama UML você deve colocar os atributos (campos da tabela) e métodos do ***modelo***, e não do controlador.

Em MVC, nem sempre se cria métodos nas classes de modelo, usa-se mais os controladores. Mas se  você tiver alguma lógica específica do modelo, ***pode*** colocar ali (não quer dizer que ***deve***, isso depende do caso).

Veja também: http://www.guj.com.br/java/114981-uml-para-mvc

Comment: Obrigado amigo! :D